# Merging more than two files with one column and common index in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have 10 .csv files with two columns. For example

file1.csv

```
Bact1,[1821932:1822487](+)
Bact2,[555760:556294](+)
Bact3,[2901866:2902424](-)
Bact4,[1104980:1105544](+)
```

file2.csv

```
Bact1,[1973928:1975194](-)
Bact2,[972152:973499](+)
Bact3,[3001035:3002739](-)
Bact4,[3331158:3332481](+)
Bact5,[712517:713771](+)
Bact5,[1376120:1377386](-)
```

file3.csv

```
Bact6,[4045708:4047781](+)
```

and so on to file10.csv The Bact1 represents a bacterial species and all the numbers including the sign represents the position of a gene. Each file represents a different gene, and there are duplicates like in the case of file2.csv

I wanted to merge these files so that I have something like this

```
Bact1    [1821932:1822487](+)    [1973928:1975194](-)    NaN
Bact2    [555760:556294](+)      [972152:973499](+)      NaN
Bact3    [2901866:2902424](-)    [3001035:3002739](-)    NaN
Bact4    [1104980:1105544](+)    [3331158:3332481](+)    NaN
Bact5    NaN                     [712517:713771](+)      NaN     
Bact5    NaN                        [1376120:1377386](-)    NaN
Bact6    NaN                     NaN                     [4045708:4047781](+)
```

I have tried to use pandas package in python, but seems like most of the functions are geared towards merging two dataframes, not more than two, or i am missing something.

I have just started programming in python last week (I normally use R), so getting stuck in what could be or atleast seems like  a simple thing.

Right now i am using:

```
    for x in range(1,10):
        df[x]=pandas.read_csv("file%s.csv" % (x),header=None,index_col=[0])
        df[x].columns=['gene%s' % (x)]
   dfjoin={}
   dfjoin=df[1].join([df[2],df[3],df[4],df[5],df[6],df[7],df[8],df[9],df[10]])
```

Result:

```
0                          gene1           gene2             gene3                 
Starkeya-novella-DSM-506     NaN     [728886:730173](+)  [731445:732615](+)     
Starkeya-novella-DSM-506     NaN     [728886:730173](+)  [9662:10994](+)    
Starkeya-novella-DSM-506     NaN     [728886:730173](+)  [9662:10994](+)     
Starkeya-novella-DSM-506     NaN     [728886:730173](+)  [9662:10994](+)
```

see gene2 and gene3, it has duplicated results copied.

Comment: If there are two Bact5 rows in file1, three Bact5 rows in file2, how many Bact5 rows do you want in the output? If it's six, then you can use join method by @Andy Hayden.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've read these in as DataFrames as follows:

```
In [11]: df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', sep=',', header=None, index_col=[0], names=['bact', 'file1'])

In [12]: df1
Out[12]: 
                      file1
bact
Bact1  [1821932:1822487](+)
Bact2    [555760:556294](+)
Bact3  [2901866:2902424](-)
Bact4  [1104980:1105544](+)
```

Then you can simply [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) them:

```
In [21]: df1.join([df2, df3])
Out[21]: 
                      file1                 file2                 file3
bact
Bact1  [1821932:1822487](+)  [1973928:1975194](-)                   NaN
Bact2    [555760:556294](+)    [972152:973499](+)                   NaN
Bact3  [2901866:2902424](-)  [3001035:3002739](-)                   NaN
Bact4  [1104980:1105544](+)  [3331158:3332481](+)                   NaN
Bact5                   NaN    [712517:713771](+)                   NaN
Bact5                   NaN  [1376120:1377386](-)                   NaN
Bact6                   NaN                   NaN  [4045708:4047781](+)
```

Comment: Hi @Andy I have added the code in my question again. The code seem to work, but there are many many duplicates. I am trying to figure out how.

Comment: @microbeatic when you do a join with 2x2 duplicates you get 4 in the joined DataFrame. It's unclear how pandas should join in this case, so you need to be more explicit to it (and tell it what do you want).

Comment: Hi @Andy I want the 'outer' or basically union of indices. But i seem to get duplicated indices are not followed by NaN, but by the duplicated values. See above for snippet of result using the code above and 'outer':

Comment: On the similar note, is there a way to merge values based on index. For example, instead of listing Bact5 in two rows, can we merge its value corresponding to file2 in one row separated by a delimeter?

Answer (score 1):

I changed your example data a little, here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = {
"file1":"""Bact1,[1821932:1822487](+)
Bact2,[555760:556294](+)
Bact3,[2901866:2902424](-)
Bact4,[1104980:1105544](+)
Bact5,[1104981:1105544](+)
Bact5,[1104982:1105544](+)""",

"file2":"""Bact1,[1973928:1975194](-)
Bact2,[972152:973499](+)
Bact3,[3001035:3002739](-)
Bact4,[3331158:3332481](+)
Bact5,[712517:713771](+)
Bact5,[1376120:1377386](-)
Bact5,[1376121:1377386](-)""",

"file3":"""Bact4,[3331150:3332481](+)
Bact6,[4045708:4047781](+)"""}

def read_file(f):
    s = pd.read_csv(f, header=None, index_col=0, squeeze=True)
    return s.groupby(s.index).apply(lambda s:pd.Series(s.values))

series = {key:read_file(io.StringIO(unicode(text)))
          for key, text in data.items()}

print pd.concat(series, axis=1)
```

output:

```
                        file1                 file2                 file3
0                                                                        
Bact1 0  [1821932:1822487](+)  [1973928:1975194](-)                   NaN
Bact2 0    [555760:556294](+)    [972152:973499](+)                   NaN
Bact3 0  [2901866:2902424](-)  [3001035:3002739](-)                   NaN
Bact4 0  [1104980:1105544](+)  [3331158:3332481](+)  [3331150:3332481](+)
Bact5 0  [1104981:1105544](+)    [712517:713771](+)                   NaN
      1  [1104982:1105544](+)  [1376120:1377386](-)                   NaN
      2                   NaN  [1376121:1377386](-)                   NaN
Bact6 0                   NaN                   NaN  [4045708:4047781](+)
```

Comment: Hi @HYRY i have 10 files like that and i dont understand how you formed 'data'? How did you read in the files?